# What database replication model do I need?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, replication, master-slave

I am on Rails 3 with a local Postgres database. What we want to do is replicate the entire database onto a second server in real time. We are thinking of using Octopus.

I'm confused about what model I'm looking for and how the master-slave model applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres 9.1 and later comes with streaming replication built in (for master-slave configurations). Check out http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/warm-standby.html#STREAMING-REPLICATION for more information on configuration and setup.

There are other third-party solutions for configuration, but I'd start there and see if that meets your needs.

Comment: I would second this.  Built-in replication has a few things to be aware of when choosing it (keep all systems as identical as possible, and only replicate between the same CPU architecture/major Pg version) but otherwise it is the simplest approach.